# probability, 2 chips drawn have either same number or color

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I've viewed similar problems to this, but I'm not understanding the logic to the question and answers behind them.

There are 5 red chips (each numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, & 5), and 3 blue chips (each numbered 1, 2, 3). You draw two chips at random, and don't replace them after drawing each of the two chips.

**What is the probability the two chips drawn have either the same number or same color?**

Can you help me figure the correct answer as well as the logic of it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The two events cannot occur simultaneously, so $P = P(\text{same color}) + P(\text{same number})$.

Comment: @AlexR I would appreciate the explanation of your comment. I just started this statistics course last week.

Comment: Well, if they have the same number, necessarily one is red and one is blue, because there is only one of the color-number combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}[1]{\color{red}{#1}}\newcommand{\B}[1]{\color{blue}{#1}}$ We shall consider the following:
$$\Omega = \{\R1,\R2,\R3,\R4,\R5,\B1,\B2,\B3\}$$
The number of ways to draw two coins from this is $\binom{|\Omega|}2 = \binom82 = 28$.
Let $A := \{(a,b) | \text{color}(a) = \text{color}(b)\}$. Then
$$A = \{ (\R1, \R2), \ldots, (\R4,\R5), (\B1, \B2), \ldots\}$$
$|A|$ is given by $\binom52 + \binom32 = 10 + 3 = 13$.
Now for $B:=\{(a,b) | \text{number}(a) = \text{number}(b)\}$.
$$B = \{(\R1, \B1), (\R2, \B2), (\R3, \B3)\}$$
$|B| = 3$ can be seen easily. Now $A\cap B = \emptyset$ from earlier considerations, so that Your total set of admissible combinations is $P = A\cup B$ and $|P| = |A| + |B| = 13 + 3 = 16$

Finally the probability is given by
$$p = \frac{|P|}{|\Omega|} = \frac{16}{28} = \frac47$$

Note that I use braces ($(,)$) for inner sets for improved readability.

Comment: This was 100% extremely helpful. You are the best!!

Answer (score 0):

If Red 5 is one of the two chosen tokens, there are seven possibilites for the other chip.  4 of them have the same color, 3 have neither the same color nor number.

If Red 5 is not one of the two tokens and Red 4 is, then there are 6 possibilities for choosing the other chip.  3 have the same color, and 3 have neither the same color nor number.

If neither Red 4 nor Red 5 are selected, then both tokens must be from Red 1 to 3 and Blue 1 to 3.  No matter which token is chosen first, 2 of the remaining 5 will share a color, 1 will share a number, and 2 will share neither a color nor a number.  Since there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to chose two tokens out of 6, $\frac{2}{5}\binom62 = \frac25 15 = 6$ will have neither rank nor color match, so $9$ will have one characteristic match.

Adding it all up, there are $7 + 6 + \binom{6}{2} = 28$ ways to choose 2 out of 8 tokens ($\binom{8}{2} = 28$ also), and $4 + 3 + 9 = 16$ will have a match, and $3 + 3 + 6 = 12$ will not.  So the probability that a characteristic will match between the tokens is $\frac{16}{28} = \frac47$.